# RDLC Report Generation On Windows is Okay But Not on Macbook

Tags: asp.net, macos, rdlc

I try to generate report RDLC, it is working okay with my Windows 10. But when I try to run on my MacOS 10.15.17. The errror below is showing. Please help check. I am thinking it is not supporting the .net framework on Macbook machine. Only Dotnet core supported. But I really need RDLC report. Because there is no better solution yet.

```
 An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
    DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libkernel32.dll, 1): image not found
    AspNetCore.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.InternalCreateIntermediateFormat(Stream definitionStream, out string description, out string language, out ParameterInfoCollection parameters, out DataSourceInfoCollection dataSources, out DataSetInfoCollection sharedDataSetReferences, out UserLocationFlags userReferenceLocation, out ArrayList dataSetsName, out bool hasExternalImages, out bool hasHyperlinks, out byte[] dataSetsHash)

ReportProcessingException: An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libkernel32.dll, 1): image not found
AspNetCore.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext)

DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report '/Users/chhinsras/Desktop/Coding/AspNetCoreRDLC/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/ReportFiles/UserDetails.rdlc' is invalid.
An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libkernel32.dll, 1): image not found
AspNetCore.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, byte[] reportDefinition, bool generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, out ControlSnapshot snapshot)

LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing.;The definition of the report '/Users/chhinsras/Desktop/Coding/AspNetCoreRDLC/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/ReportFiles/UserDetails.rdlc' is invalid.
An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libkernel32.dll, 1): image not found
AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libkernel32.dll, 1): image not found
AspNetCore.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.InternalCreateIntermediateFormat(Stream definitionStream, out string description, out string language, out ParameterInfoCollection parameters, out DataSourceInfoCollection dataSources, out DataSetInfoCollection sharedDataSetReferences, out UserLocationFlags userReferenceLocation, out ArrayList dataSetsName, out bool hasExternalImages, out bool hasHyperlinks, out byte[] dataSetsHash)
AspNetCore.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.CreateIntermediateFormat(byte[] definition, out string description, out string language, out ParameterInfoCollection parameters, out DataSourceInfoCollection dataSources, out DataSetInfoCollection sharedDataSetReferences, out UserLocationFlags userReferenceLocation, out ArrayList dataSetsName, out bool hasExternalImages, out bool hasHyperlinks, out byte[] dataSetsHash)
AspNetCore.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CompileOdpReport(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, out string reportDescription, out string reportLanguage, out ParameterInfoCollection parameters, out DataSourceInfoCollection dataSources, out DataSetInfoCollection sharedDataSetReferences, out UserLocationFlags userReferenceLocation, out ArrayList dataSetsName, out bool hasExternalImages, out bool hasHyperlinks, out byte[] dataSetsHash)
AspNetCore.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext)

Show raw exception details
ReportProcessingException: An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libkernel32.dll, 1): image not found
AspNetCore.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext)
AspNetCore.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, byte[] reportDefinition, bool generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, out ControlSnapshot snapshot)

Show raw exception details
DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report '/Users/chhinsras/Desktop/Coding/AspNetCoreRDLC/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/ReportFiles/UserDetails.rdlc' is invalid. An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libkernel32.dll, 1): image not found
AspNetCore.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, byte[] reportDefinition, bool generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, out ControlSnapshot snapshot)
AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(PreviewItemContext itemContext, bool rebuild, out ControlSnapshot snapshot)
AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport()
AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalService.AspNetCore.Reporting.ILocalProcessingHost.CompileReport()
AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()

Show raw exception details
LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing.;The definition of the report '/Users/chhinsras/Desktop/Coding/AspNetCoreRDLC/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/ReportFiles/UserDetails.rdlc' is invalid. An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libkernel32.dll, 1): image not found
AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport.InternalRender(string format, bool allowInternalRenderers, string deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, out Warning[] warnings)
AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport.InternalRender(string format, bool allowInternalRenderers, string deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, out string mimeType, out string encoding, out string fileNameExtension, out string[] streams, out Warning[] warnings)
AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport.Render(string format, string deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, out string mimeType, out string encoding, out string fileNameExtension, out string[] streams, out Warning[] warnings)
AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalReport.Execute(RenderType renderType, int pageIndex, Dictionary<string, string> parameters, string findString)
AspNetCoreRDLC.Services.ReportService.GenerateReportAsync(string reportName, string fileType) in ReportService.cs
+
                result = report.Execute(GetRenderType("pdf"), 1, parameters);
AspNetCoreRDLC.Controllers.ReportController.GetPDF(string reportName, string fileType) in ReportController.cs
+
            var returnString = _reportService.GenerateReportAsync(reportName, fileType);
lambda_method(Closure , object , object[] )
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(object target, object[] parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
```

Comment: What library are you using for the RDLC? It it a NuGet package?

Comment: https://github.com/chhinsras/AspNetCoreRDLC. this is my repo. it is working on windows, not mac

Comment: You don't need to repeat yourself. You already stated it's working on Windows but not Mac in the question.

Comment: I wouldn't expect kernel32.dll to be available on a platform besides Windows, because that's part of the Windows OS. Looks like one of the libraries you're consuming has a dependency on Windows.

Comment: I think so. but any solution?

Comment: I really need rdlc or alternative, but not enterprise price

Comment: Why do you need RDLC at all? What are you using it to do? Generate reports in some format? What format?

Comment: I need pdf, word, and excel file. Using html is really hard for paper size and template. RDLC is easy to do so

Comment: I try using ngx export as for angular project. but it is really hard to get proper template word/excel/pdf ...

Comment: There are libraries capable of generating PDF, Word, and Excel files entirely in managed code, that don't depend on the OS. You should probably look into those rather than RDLC.

Comment: what are they? can you recommend

Comment: You can use your favorite search engine to search for "c# generate pdf", "c# generate excel document", and "c# generate word document"

Comment: I try but not easy as RDLC. which easy to design the template. No responsive problem in rendering

Comment: Update: In order to support Mac, I need to intergrate with ReportViewerCore.NETCore library. Here is my repo: github.com/chhinsras/AspNetCoreRDLC